# How to copy the text from Column A to Column B, according to font size

Tags: excel, fonts, copy

I want to copy all the text contains is Cell from Column A to Column B, which font size is "14".

I want like this, find the image here:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a simple loop:

```
Sub copy14()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range("A:A"))
        If r.Font.Size = 14 Then r.Copy r.Offset(0, 1)
    Next r
End Sub
```